# Ruby on Rails: Executing JAR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, jar, io, popen

Folks, i'm trying to execute a jar file inside RoR. Thanks to SO, I figured using IO::popen calls to execute a jar file.

Requirements: 
   - To login to site: To let our company employees login. Its a Java library which does some magic and figures if the username/password is valid. Which I did using,

```
result = IO::popen("java -cp auth.jar com.name.auth.LDAPLookup " + params[:username] + " " + params[:password]).read
p result
```

output: ["Authorized", "email", "id"]

- No input sanitizing done. This is risky. Anyone could type something up in username/password and that will be executed in the server.

I'm not sure how to do this. One option I want to try is to use fork() or Process APIs to launch "java" and pass arguments. Couldn't figure out however. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the issue you mention, this sounds pretty painful in terms of performance (you're waiting around for the JVM to start up on every request, after all).

Two solutions jump out at me:

- Look what the library does, and see if you really need to call out to Java for this; in particular, if it's just a question of making a lookup in an LDAP directory with a set of canned parameters, there are plenty of gems for that
- If you *must* make use of Java classes from Ruby, strongly consider using [JRuby](http://jruby.org/), which will let you call the Java class in question directly, with neither the overhead of restarting the JVM on each call, nor the risk which comes with trying to correctly escape your arguments from Ruby to the shell to the JVM, and back.

Comment: Thanks for reply Jimwise. I agree, it is a pain with performance. I really do not have enough time before demo to lookup gems to do LDAP lookup. I like your JRuby idea! When I did a quick search on jruby in SO, people complained about available GEMs and performance of Jruby vs Ruby. I decided then to switch using regular Ruby. How easy would it be to move to JRuby at this point? Any pointers?

Comment: It should be pretty easy to try out JRuby -- if you have JRuby installed, your workflow on JRuby won't be much different than what you're doing now, just get in the habbit of typing `jruby -S $command` where you're typing `$command` today. To test your Rails app, for instance, you'll do `jruby -S bundle install ; jruby -S bundle exec rails s` (or similar). Or you can use RVM's JRuby support ( https://rvm.io/interpreters/jruby/ ) to make even this change go away. :-)